# How to select data from xml file by attribute?

Tags: php, xml

here is my xml file note.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<agents>
    <agent>
    <id>1</id>
    <image> img/primary-nav-logo.png</image>
    <name>Tommy Jenkin</name>
    <company>CJenkins Insurance</company>
    <street>Insurance150 S State Stree</street>
    <city>Linkend</city>
    <phone>(773) 561-4331</phone>
    </agent>
    <agent>
    <id>2</id>
    <image> img/primary-nav-logo.png</image>
    <name>Tommy Jenkin</name>
    <company>CJenkins Insurance</company>
    <street>Insurance150 S State Stree</street>
    <city>Linkend</city>
    <phone>(773) 561-4331</phone>
    </agent>
</agents>
```

and i have to print xml record of id 1 and i have write code in php like this

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("note.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach($xml->xpath('//agent') as $item) { 
    $row = simplexml_load_string($item->asXML());
    $v = $row->xpath('//id[. ="1"]');
    if($v[0]){ 
        print $item->id; 
        print $item->image; 
        print $item->name; 
        print $item->company; 
        print $item->street; 
        print $item->city;
        print $item->phone; 
    }
    else{
        echo 'No records';
    }
?>
```

please suggest me where i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

you have severall ways, here is one of them

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($input);
$agents= $xml->getElementsByTagName("agent");
foreach ($agents as $agent) {
    $elements = $xml->getElementsByTagName("id");
    $id = $elements->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Too complicated, do it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("note.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$results = "/agents/agent[id = '1']";
foreach($results as $item) { 

    print $item->id; 
    print $item->image; 
    // etc        
}
```